# Klipper pop-up menu does not exist anymore

Tags: 10.10, gnome, clipboard-manager

I have been using Klipper as my clipboard manager and it was quiet flexible to use it's pop-up menu shortcut.  But in ubuntu 10.10 it seems that there is no shortcut key to trigger the klipper popup menu.

Is there anyway to enable the popup menu shortcut for klipper?.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/11488/6969#29216

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the klipper pop-up menu with your mouse, go to 'Configure Klipper' go to Advanced and then Shortcut Options. You should be able to configure/re-configure the shortcut key in here. If this fails, then the Desktop Environment mught be overriding that key combination for a different function.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Klipper

Hope this helps,
Bodsda

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I have already tried this and found that there is no such key in Shortcut Options. It was there in 10.04 but in 10.10 it is exist no more

Comment: You could uninstall the 10.10 version, grab the deb from packages.ubuntu.com for 10.04 and then install that. If you do an upgrade, it might keep the functionality. Failing that, you could pin the 10.04 version so that it doesnt update.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a known bug with no workaround for GNOME: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=244620

Answer (score 1):

if you are using KDE, you have to specify the shortcut in system tray settings (instead of in the klipper global shortcuts). See https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=244620#c41

Comment: No. I am a great fan of Gnome.

Comment: Thank you, user11900.  (The workaround is to assign a shortcut key in System Tray Settings > Entries > Klipper.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about switching to Parcellite, which is good integrated in Gnome?

Comment: Yes I have already tried it . But I still prefer klipper. Easy to use, configure and so on